# Reading a matrix created using an operator

Tags: c++, class, matrix, operator-keyword

Hello stackoverflow community.  I need some help with a bit of code (I am a new to C++ so be gentle).  I am trying to use operator() to create a matrix, store data from an input file, then write to an output file.  The below code has been simplified a bit.  The header file is as follows:

```
//Data Header File

#ifndef Data_h
#define Data_h

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Data
{
private:
    int d_elems;
    int rows_, cols_;
    int dataRows;
    int *p;
public:
    //Constructor
    femData();
    femData(int Row, int Col);

    //Copy Constructor
    //femData(const int d_elems);

    //Destructor
    virtual ~femData();

    //Operator
    int& operator() (int Rows, int Cols);

    //Functions
    void readData(istream &inp);  //Read Data from Input File
    void writeData(ostream &out);  //Write Data from Output File
};
#endif
```

Any my .cpp file:

```
//.cpp file
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Data.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

Data::Data() {}  //Blanket Constructor

Data::Data(int Row, int Col) //Matrix Constructor
    : rows_ (Row), cols_ (Col)
{
    if (Row == 0 || Col == 0)
    {
        cout << "\nMatrix is Zero..." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }
    p = new int[Row * Col];
}

int& Data::operator()(int Rows, int Cols)  //Operator for Matrix
{
    if (Rows >= rows_ || Cols >= cols_)
    {
        cout << "\nMatrix subscript out of bounds\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }
    return p[cols_ * Rows + Cols];
}

Data::~Data() { /*delete[] p;*/}  //Destructor

void Data::readData(istream &inp)
{
    inp >> dataRows;
    int e_id;
    //Data (dataRows, 10);  //How would I call this constructor?
    rows_ = dataRows;
    cols_ = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataRows; i++)
    {
        inp >> e_id;

        if ((e_id - 1) != i)
        {
            cout << "\nError Reading Data..." << endl;
            cout << "Program Will End\n!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }

        (*this)(i, 0) = d_eid;

        for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            inp >> (*this)(i, j);
        }
    }

    void femData::writeData(ostream & out)
    {
        //Output Info
        out << setfill('-') << setw(90) << "-" << endl;
        out << setfill(' ') << setw(34) << " Matrix Information " << endl;
        out << setfill('-') << setw(90) << "-" << "\n\n" << endl;
        out << setfill(' ');
        out << setw(10) << "ID";
        out << setw(10) << "Data 1";
        out << setw(10) << "Data 2";
        out << setw(10) << "Data 3";
        out << setw(10) << "Data 4";
        out << setw(10) << "Data 5";
        out << setw(10) << "Data 6";
        out << setw(10) << "Data 7";
        out << setw(10) << "Data 8" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataRows; i++)
        {
            out << setw(7) << ((p + i) + 0);
            out << setw(10) << ((p + i) + 1);
            out << setw(10) << ((p + i) + 2);
            out << setw(10) << ((p + i) + 3);
            out << setw(10) << ((p + i) + 4);
            out << setw(10) << ((p + i) + 5);
            out << setw(10) << ((p + i) + 6);
            out << setw(10) << ((p + i) + 7);
            out << setw(10) << ((p + i) + 8) << endl;
            //Note ((p + i) + 8) is omitted
        }
    }
```

The issue I am having is with the output.  When the WriteData function is called, it writes to an output file, but does not write the data it read.  Instead all that is written is `{0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8} {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9} {etc.}` where `{is used here to denote different rows}`

Additionally, if I try to output `d_elems(i,0)` instead of `((d_elems + i) + 0)` the compiler tells me I need a pointer to function type.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `readData` is wrong. You read data in a local object, `Data d_data(dataRows,10);` which is then destroyed at the end of the function. You are not filling in the data on your current instance. You need to read directly into `p'

```
inp >> p[i * rows_ + j];
```

or use the `operator()` you defined on the current instance, like

```
inp >> (*this)(i,j); // this is preferable
```

Side issue: you are missing the declaration of `p` in the class header file, `int *p;`.

Side issue 2: Your `int& Data::operator()(int Rows, int Cols)` is confusing, try using `int& Data::operator()(int i, int j)`, and `return p[i * _cols + j];` as it makes it much easier to read.

Comment: I was curious about that, so I need to replace **d_data(I,0)** with **p(I,0)**?

Comment: @joe not `p(i,0)`, as there is no `operator()(int,int)` for pointers. Use indirectly the `operator()(int,int)` you just defined, and apply it to your current instance, `inp >> *this(i, j);` If not, you can write directly to `p` as `inp >> p[i * rows_ + j];` So you need to replace all `d_data(i,j)` with either `*this(i,j)` or `p[i * rows_ + j]`.

Comment: @joe typo in my comment above, should be `p[i * cols_ + j]` and `(*this)(i,j)` (thanks @Quentin)

Comment: @ vsoftco: Alright, so I updated what I am using above and an still running into issues.  Issue 1: when I run the above, I get the following error: **Unhandled exception at 0x00CED9EB in Project 2.0.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.**  Issue 2: How would I call the constructor as indicated above by `Data (dataRows, 10);` if using the `(*this)(i,j)`?

Comment: @joe When you invoke `void Data::readData(istream &inp)` your object is already constructed, so it has `rows_` rows and `cols_` columns. There is no need to re-input the number of rows and columns (in fact it's wrong, since you may use a different number and perform out of bounds access). So, use `rows_` and `cols_` variables inside your function `readData`. If you want to read `rows_` and `cols_` from a file, then you need to first delete the previous allocated pointer `p` and reallocate. Remember that the constructor is called *first* when you create an object.